# GroupArray by two fields, and sum values of second

Tags: sql, database, clickhouse

I'm using ClickHouse, I want group data by field1 (keywords) and in other field show uniq urls and for each URL sum values of clicks (other field),

Raw data

```
keyword |   URL                                     |  clicks   | impression|   position|   ctr
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
kw1     |   https://mydomain.dev/url1.html          |   10      |   100     |       2   |   **0,10**
kw1     |   https://mydomain.dev/other-url2.html    |   20      |   434     |       3   |   0,05
kw1     |   https://mydomain.dev/url3.html          |   30      |   345     |       4   |   0,09
kw1     |   https://mydomain.dev/url1.html          |   10      |   40      |       5   |   0,25
kw1     |   https://mydomain.dev/other-url2.html    |   22      |   42      |       6   |   0,52
kw1     |   https://mydomain.dev/other-url2.html    |   23      |   43      |       7   |   0,53
Kw2     |   https://mydomain.dev/other-url-data-a   |   435     |   3243    |       1   |   **0,13**
Kw2     |   https://mydomain.dev/other-url-data-b   |   34      |   43      |       4   |   0,79
Kw2     |   https://mydomain.dev/other-url-data-c   |   23      |   433     |       7   |   0,05
Kw2     |   https://mydomain.dev/other-url-data-b   |   232     |   343     |       13  |   0,68
Kw2     |   https://mydomain.dev/other-url-data-a   |   23      |   232     |       14  |   0,10
Kw2     |   https://mydomain.dev/other-url-data-d   |   3       |   34      |       15  |   0,09
Kw2     |   https://mydomain.dev/other-url-data-d   |   23      |   345     |       16  |   0,07
Kw2     |   https://mydomain.dev/other-url-data-c   |   2       |   43      |       17  |   0,05
```

And desired result:

- get ctr from best position for each kw(bold)
- and group uniq url and sum clicks and impressions by url

res

```
KW, |   URL  clicks : impressions               Cli:Impr|   otalclicks  | TotalUmp  |average    |   ctr     |best_position_by_kw
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
kw1 |   https://mydomain.dev/url1.html          20:140  |       115     |   1004    |3,62       |   10,00%  |   2
    |   https://mydomain.dev/other-url2.html    65:519, |               |           |           |           |          
    |   https://mydomain.dev/url3.html          30:345  |               |           |           |           |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
kw2 |   https //mydomain.dev/other-url-data-a   667:3475|       775     |   4716    |4,43       |   13,41%  |   1           
        https //mydomain.dev/other-url-data-b   266 386 |               |           |
        https //mydomain.dev/other-url-data-c   25 379  |               |           |
        https //mydomain.dev/other-url-data-d   26 476  |               |           |
```

**TABLES AND DATA:**

*Principal table*

```
CREATE TABLE users_data
(
    `fecha` Date,
    `consulta` String,
    `landing` String,
    `clicks` UInt32,
    `impresiones` UInt32,
    `posicion` Float32,
    `ctr` Float32,
    `dispositivo` String,
    `pais` String
)
ENGINE = MergeTree(fecha, landing, 8192)
```

*Table from file* to get "Grupo" field, I only need group of this table (used to group similar kws)

```
SELECT
    consulta,
    any(Grupo) AS Grupo
FROM
    file('kw-2020.csv',
    'CSVWithNames',
    'fecha Date,  consulta String,  landing String,  clicks UInt32,  impresiones UInt32,  posicion Float32,  ctr Float32,  dispositivo String,  pais String,Grupo String')
GROUP BY
    consulta
```

**DATA OF users_data:**

```
INSERT INTO  table_name  (fecha,consulta,landing,clicks,impresiones,posicion,ctr,dispositivo,pais) VALUES ('2020-06-22','electricidad presupuestos electricos ejemplos','https://mydomain.dev/directory/ld-domain-de-presupuesto-de-elctricidad.php',0,1,7.0,0.0,'MOBILE','chl');
INSERT INTO  table_name  (fecha,consulta,landing,clicks,impresiones,posicion,ctr,dispositivo,pais) VALUES ('2020-06-22','modelo de carta de recomendacion laboral peru','https://mydomain.dev/directory/ld-domain-de-carta-de-662.php',0,1,5.0,0.0,'DESKTOP','per');
INSERT INTO  table_name  (fecha,consulta,landing,clicks,impresiones,posicion,ctr,dispositivo,pais) VALUES ('2020-06-22','carta de ofrecimiento de servicios a una empresa','https://mydomain.dev/directory/ld-domain-carta-para-ofrecer-servicios.php',0,3,1.0,0.0,'DESKTOP','slv');
INSERT INTO  table_name  (fecha,consulta,landing,clicks,impresiones,posicion,ctr,dispositivo,pais) VALUES ('2020-06-22','ejemplo de estrofa','https://mydomain.dev/directory/ld-ejemplo-de-estrofa.php',0,1,28.0,0.0,'DESKTOP','nld');
INSERT INTO  table_name  (fecha,consulta,landing,clicks,impresiones,posicion,ctr,dispositivo,pais) VALUES ('2020-06-22','carta de intención de servicios profesionales','https://mydomain.dev/directory/goto-domain-de-carta-de-384.php',0,1,5.0,0.0,'DESKTOP','mex');
INSERT INTO  table_name  (fecha,consulta,landing,clicks,impresiones,posicion,ctr,dispositivo,pais) VALUES ('2020-06-22','ejemplos de presupuesto base cero','https://mydomain.dev/directory/ld-domain-de-presupuesto-base-cero.php',0,1,92.0,0.0,'DESKTOP','mex');
INSERT INTO  table_name  (fecha,consulta,landing,clicks,impresiones,posicion,ctr,dispositivo,pais) VALUES ('2020-06-22','como se hace una carta de recomendacion','https://mydomain.dev/directory/ld-domain-de-carta-de-662.php',0,1,77.0,0.0,'DESKTOP','twn');
INSERT INTO  table_name  (fecha,consulta,landing,clicks,impresiones,posicion,ctr,dispositivo,pais) VALUES ('2020-06-22','carta de oferta de productos a clientes','https://mydomain.dev/directory/ld-domain-carta-para-ofrecer-servicios.php',0,1,1.0,0.0,'DESKTOP','esp');
INSERT INTO  table_name  (fecha,consulta,landing,clicks,impresiones,posicion,ctr,dispositivo,pais) VALUES ('2020-06-22','investigación hemerográfica','https://mydomain.dev/directory/ld-ejemplo-de-ficha-hemerogrfica.php',0,1,44.0,0.0,'DESKTOP','rus');
INSERT INTO  table_name  (fecha,consulta,landing,clicks,impresiones,posicion,ctr,dispositivo,pais) VALUES ('2020-06-22','carta de intención de servicios profesionales','https://mydomain.dev/directory/goto-domain-de-carta-de-384.php',2,6,2.0,0.0,'DESKTOP','col');
```

**Data from file**

```
   "grupo"    |  "consulta"
-----------------------------------------------------------
pedido    |  carta de pedido ejemplo
carta     |  carta de ofrecimiento de servicios a una empresa
carta     |  carta de intenciÃ³n de servicios profesionales
pedido    |  carta de pedido
carta     |  carta de oferta de productos a clientes
carta     |  carta de intenciÃ³n de servicios profesionales
pedido    |  carta de pedido ejemplo
carta     |  carta de presentacion a una empresa ofreciendo servicios
otros     |  rescisiÃ³n de contrato modelo
pedido    |  carta de pedidos ejemplos
carta     |  carta de presentacion de empresas de servicios
carta     |  carta solicitando beca universitaria
pedido    |  carta comercial de pedido
carta     |  carta a clientes para ofrecer servicios
otros     |  casilla 99 modelo 390
pedido    |  carta de pedido
carta     |  carta de oferta de servicios
carta     |  carta de intencion de renta
pedido    |  carta de pedido
carta     |  carta de ofrecimiento de productos
otros     |  contrato de leasing modelo
pedido    |  carta de pedidos
carta     |  carta de presentacion de empresa de servicios
otros     |  rescisiÃ³n de contrato modelo
pedido    |  carta de pedidos
carta     |  carta de presentacion de empresa para ofrecer productos
carta     |  modelo de carta de intencion academica
pedido    |  carta de solicitud de pedido
carta     |  carta de presentacion de servicios
otros     |  modelo de solicitud para beca de estudios
pedido    |  carta de solicitud de pedido
carta     |  carta de presentacion de servicios
otros     |  anexo ampliacion contrato de arras
carta     |  carta de solicitud de un producto
carta     |  carta para ofrecer servicios
otros     |  modelo de rescisiÃ³n de contrato
pedido    |  carta comercial pedido
carta     |  carta a clientes para ofrecer servicios
otros     |  formato de rescisiÃ³n de contrato de compraventa de inmueble
pedido    |  carta de anulacion de pedido
carta     |  carta a clientes para ofrecer servicios
otros     |  contrato de trabajo para extranjeros en chile
pedido    |  carta de pedido
carta     |  carta de ofrecer servicios
otros     |  modelo de recision de contrato
pedido    |  carta de pedido
carta     |  carta de oferta de servicios
otros     |  formato de rescisiÃ³n de contrato de prestacion de servicios
pedido    |  carta de pedido
carta"    |  carta de ofrecimiento de servicios
```

I need:
For each "grupo" (contains many kws) I need

All distinct "consulta" field for each group, and also for each of consulta: in group
-value of the "CTR" where "posicion" field is lowest
-"posicion" of last date(s)

- clicks and  impressions for each distinct "consulta"
- % acummulative of impressions and clicks for each consulta in group

-all distinct "landing" and  sum "clicks" and "impressions"
-% acummulative of impressions and clicks for each URL

I tried this sentence:

```
    SELECT 
    grupo,
    groupUniqArray(consulta) as KWS,
    groupUniqArray(landing) as landings,
    topK(1)(mediaPonderada)[1] AS PosicionFrecuente,
    anyLast(mediaPonderada) AS UltimaPosicion,
    varSamp(imp) AS varianza2,
    sqrt(varianza2) AS desviacion2,
    stddevSamp(imp) AS stdImp2,
    count() AS cnt,
    groupArray((consulta, imp, clicks2, round((clicks2 * 100) / imp, 3), mediaPonderada)) AS consulta_imp,
    arraySum(x -> (x.2), consulta_imp) AS total_imp,
    total_imp / cnt AS media,
    arraySum(x -> (x.3), consulta_imp) AS total_clicks,
    round((total_clicks * 100) / total_imp, 2) AS ctr,
    arrayMap(x -> ((100 / total_imp) * (x.2)), consulta_imp) AS percent_imp,
    arrayCumSum(percent_imp) AS acc_percent_imp,
    consulta_imp[1] AS total_ctr2,
    total_ctr2.4 AS ctr2
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        grupo,
        consulta,
        landing,
        quantileDeterministic(0.5)(impresiones, 10) AS detImp,
        avg(impresiones) AS medImp,
        varSamp(impresiones) AS varMuestraImp,
        varPop(impresiones) AS varPobImp,
        count() AS cnt,
        sum(clicks) AS clicks2,
        sum(impresiones) AS imp,
        round((clicks2 * 100) / imp, 2) AS ctr,
        round((posicion * impresiones) / impresiones, 0) AS mediaPonderada,
        arrayMap(2)(x -> round(x, 2), max([round(posicion, 0), clicks, impresiones])) AS arrclicks,
        varSamp(impresiones) AS varianza,
        avg(impresiones) AS media,
        stddevSamp(impresiones) AS stdImp,
        stddevPop(impresiones) AS stdPopImp,
        sqrt(varianza) AS desviacion,
        stdImp / media AS desvMedia
    FROM (
         SELECT 
            fecha,
            consulta,
            landing,
            clicks,
            impresiones,
            posicion,
            ctr,
            dispositivo,
            pais,
            Grupo as grupo
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM GSC_https_Modelode_com2 ghmc 
            WHERE fecha > '2020-01-01'
        ) AS t1
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT 
                consulta,
                any(Grupo) AS Grupo
            FROM file('kw-2020.csv', 'CSVWithNames', 'fecha Date,  consulta String,  landing String,  clicks UInt32,  impresiones UInt32,  posicion Float32,  ctr Float32,  dispositivo String,  pais String,`Raiz semantica` String,Volumen UInt32,clickstream UInt32,cpc Float32,Grupo String')
            GROUP BY consulta
        ) AS t2 USING (consulta)
        ORDER BY fecha ASC
    )
    WHERE (fecha > '2020-06-01')
    GROUP BY 
        grupo,
        mediaPonderada,
        landing,consulta
    ORDER BY 
        mediaPonderada ASC,
        imp DESC
)
GROUP BY grupo
```

Doesn't work, url is repeated and don't sum clicks and impressiones

```
kw      |miArr                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
--------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
kw1     |['[https://mydomain.dev/url1.html, 2]','[https://mydomain.dev/url1.html, 1]','[https://mydomain.dev/url1.html#alternativas, 0]','
kw2     |['[https://mydomain.dev/url2.html, 1]','[https://mydomain.dev/url2.html, 0]']
```

Comment: give us create table / insert test data, otherwise your question is hard to understand

Comment: Principal table
CREATE TABLE users_data
(
    `fecha` Date,
    `consulta` String,
    `landing` String,
    `clicks` UInt32,
    `impresiones` UInt32,
    `posicion` Float32,
    `ctr` Float32,
    `dispositivo` String,
    `pais` String
)
ENGINE = MergeTree(fecha, landing, 8192)

Comment: Second table, (file csv)!
FROM
 file('kw-2020.csv',
 'CSVWithNames',
 'fecha Date,  consulta String,  landing String,  clicks UInt32,  impresiones UInt32,  posicion Float32,  ctr Float32,  dispositivo String,  pais String,`,Volumen UInt32,clickstream UInt32,cpc Float32,Grupo String')

Comment: I need:
 
for each "grupo" (contains many kws) I need
-all distinct "consulta" field for each group, and also for each of consulta: in group
 -value of the "CTR" where "posicion" field is lowest
 -"posicion" of last date(s)
 -clicks and  impressions for each distinct "consulta" 
 -% acummulative of impressions and clicks for each consulta in group
 
-all distinct "landing" and  sum "clicks" and "impressions"
 -% acummulative of impressions and clicks for each URL



Comment: How can I share INSERTS or data with you?

Comment: place create table and inserts into your question.

Comment: ready! it's right?

Comment: anyway it's unreadable. It needs two hours to understand your question. Try to simplify. I don't really understand what is the problem with current select.

Comment: Ok, Leave me a short time and I will be able to summarize it well and clearly. Thanks for your patience

Answer (score 0):

```
select keyword, groupArray((URL, cl, imp)), sum(cl), sum(imp) 
from (
from keyword,URL, sum(clicks) cl, sum(impression) imp
group by keyword,URL)
group by keyword
```

Comment: Thanks Denny, but How do you select the first CTR value?

Comment: groupArray(1)(ctr)

Comment: Denny, first of all  sorry my english , I can't fully explain it but. I need the value of the CTR where the position is lowest

Comment: I don't care. I don't speak English. I speak SQL only.